# Non-Negative Integer Solution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

Hey guys there is this question in the picture [image: [1]] i have uploaded, i fail to understand how to solve, can you please, help me out, and also give me explanation regarding it?

Thank You, With Respect Umer Selmani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_i=i+y_i$, where the $y_i$ are non-negative integers. Then the sum of the $y_i$ is $8$.

Do you know how to solve this problem now? The answer is
$\begin{pmatrix}8+6-1\\8\\\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: i don't get the point, how y(i) gets to become 8, when i is [1-6]

Comment: The sum of the $x_i$ is $29$ and is also the same as $1+2+3+4+5+6+y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5+y_6$.

Comment: So, the solution will be > 29 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 = x1 +x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6,
8=x1 +x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6, and then as the "Combination with repetition" formula  says (n+r-1 r), the result will be (8 + 6 -1   8), right?

Comment: I think you have started to type the correct answer. I have put it into my solution for reference.